# How to correct my code so it doesn't give errors after being minified?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, minify

My angular code works just fine before it is minified:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ionic.contrib.ui.tinderCards2'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {})
  .directive('noScroll', function($document) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
        $document.on('touchmove', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      }
    }})
  .controller('CardsCtrl', function($scope, TDCardDelegate, $timeout) {

    var qc        = 0, // Current Question counter
        points    = 0, // Current points
        validIdx = cardTypes.valid,
        $points   = ("p>span");


    $scope.cards = {
      master: Array.prototype.slice.call(cardTypes, 0),
      active: Array.prototype.slice.call(cardTypes, 0),
      discards: [],
      liked: [],
      disliked: []
    }

    $scope.points = 0;

    $scope.cardDestroyed = function(index) {
      $scope.cards.active.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.addCard = function() {
      var newCard = cardTypes[0];
      $scope.cards.active.push(angular.extend({}, newCard));
    }

    $scope.refreshCards = function() {
      // Set $scope.cards to null so that directive reloads
      $scope.cards.active = null;
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.cards.active = Array.prototype.slice.call($scope.cards.master, 0);
      });
      $scope.points = 0;
    }

    $scope.$on('removeCard', function(event, element, card) {
      var discarded = $scope.cards.master.splice($scope.cards.master.indexOf(card), 1);
      $scope.cards.discards.push(discarded);
    });

    $scope.cardSwipedLeft = function(index) {
      var card = $scope.cards.active[index];
      $scope.cards.disliked.push(card);

      var givenAnswer = 0,
          correctAnswer = card.valid;  

      //increment the points variable if the answer is correct:
      if (givenAnswer === correctAnswer) {
          $scope.points++;             
      } 
    };

    $scope.cardSwipedRight = function(index) {
        // console.log('RIGHT SWIPE');
        var card = $scope.cards.active[index];
        $scope.cards.liked.push(card);

       var givenAnswer = 1,
           correctAnswer = card.valid;

        //increment the points variable if the answer is correct:
        if (givenAnswer === correctAnswer) {
            $scope.points++;             
        } 

    };

    $scope.onClickNotFamily = function(index) {
        // console.log('RIGHT CLICK');
        var card = $scope.cards.active[index];
        $scope.cards.liked.push(card);

        var givenAnswer = 0,
            correctAnswer = card.valid;  

        //increment the points variable if the answer is correct:
        if (givenAnswer === correctAnswer) {
            $scope.points++;             
        } 

    };

    $scope.onClickFamily = function(index) {
      // console.log('RIGHT CLICK');
      var card = $scope.cards.active[index];
      $scope.cards.liked.push(card);

      var givenAnswer = 1,
          correctAnswer = card.valid;  

      //increment the points variable if the answer is correct:
      if (givenAnswer === correctAnswer) { 
          $scope.points++;             
      }

    };
  })
  .controller('CardCtrl', function($scope, TDCardDelegate) {});
```

But once minified I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: b
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=b
    at http://win.deezer.family/v1/js/ionic.bundle.js:13437:12
    at http://win.deezer.family/v1/js/ionic.bundle.js:17787:19
    at getService (http://win.deezer.family/v1/js/ionic.bundle.js:17940:39)
    at injectionArgs (http://win.deezer.family/v1/js/ionic.bundle.js:17964:58)
    at Object.invoke (http://win.deezer.family/v1/js/ionic.bundle.js:17986:18)
    at runInvokeQueue (http://win.deezer.family/v1/js/ionic.bundle.js:17887:35)
    at http://win.deezer.family/v1/js/ionic.bundle.js:17896:11
    at forEach (http://win.deezer.family/v1/js/ionic.bundle.js:13690:20)
    at loadModules (http://win.deezer.family/v1/js/ionic.bundle.js:17877:5)
    at createInjector (http://win.deezer.family/v1/js/ionic.bundle.js:17799:19)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter&p1=Error%3A…20(http%3A%2F%2Fwin.deezer.family%2Fv1%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A17799%3A19)
```

I am new to angular and also the minification process. Does anyone spot something that might be causing problems after being minified?

If so could you please provide an exampe on how I can fix it?

I appreciate any help. Thank you all!

Comment: follow https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification

Answer (score 0):

Add injector annotations.

There are a few ways to do this. When using the prototype pattern you can easily just add `$inject = [...]` to your prototypes.

Since you are not using this pattern, the inline array annotations would be the easiest path.

Example:

```
.directive('noScroll', ['$document', function($document) {
    // . . .
}])
.controller('CardsCtrl', 
    ['$scope', 'TDCardDelegate', '$timeout', 
    function($scope, TDCardDelegate, $timeout) {

    // . . .
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you minify your JS files, they are obfuscated.
When that happens the code that you wrote is modified.

For example:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', function($scope, greeter) {
   $scope.bar = greeter.foo;
});
```

After being minified, could resolve in something like this:

```
c.controller('MyController',function(a,b){a.bar=b.foo;});
```

Params **$scope** and **greeter** are replace with **a** and **b**.

Then when you run the minified code, the Angular dependency injerctor fails when it tries to inject the **a** and **b** dependencies, because they don't exists.

But...

By using dependency annotation can fix it. You could use:

**Inline Array Annotation**

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}]);
```

**$inject Property Annotation**

```
var MyController = function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'greeter'];
someModule.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

More info here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/docs/guide/di

Comment: Can you please say why it sucks, give a little explanation and not just a link.